# Fourier Series piecewise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

[image]

Can someone please explain why the integral gose from -1 to 1 to (0 to 1)
how does this happen?

Comment: Well, what's the definition of $f$? Can you compute $\int_{-1}^0 f$?

Comment: f =0 between there..

Comment: Yes. So can you compute the integral?

Comment: Its C, so u ignore?

Comment: No. Go back to the definition of the integral and think about what $\int_{-1}^0 0 \, dx$ represents.

Comment: Remember, we're dealing with *definite integrals* here, not antiderivatives.

Comment: integral of 0 is 0?

Answer (score 1):

It is a general strategy to break integrals of piecewise functions at the boundaries of the pieces.  This means that we have simple recipes for the functions in each resulting integral.  In your case,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1} \; &\begin{cases} 0, & -1 \leq x < 0 \\ x^2, & 0 \leq x < 1 \end{cases} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \int_{-1}^{0} \; \begin{cases} 0, & -1 \leq x < 0 \\ x^2, & 0 \leq x < 1 \end{cases} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{1} \; \begin{cases} 0, & -1 \leq x < 0 \\ x^2, & 0 \leq x < 1 \end{cases} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= \int_{-1}^{0} \; 0 \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{1} \; x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
    &= 0 + \int_{0}^{1} \; x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
\end{align*}

Notice that once we split the interval of integration at the boundaries of the pieces of the definition of $f$, we only keep the one recipe in that interval.  Then the subsequent integrals are much easier to work with.